# How do i do a Command Cooldown?

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

i was wondering how to make a Command Cool-down for a single command and not all the other commands? it would be much appreciated if someone helps me out on this, Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to have to create a `Collection()` that will contain the users that have executed a command and then have a `client.setTimeout()` function to remove the users after a set time from the `Collection()` so that they can use commands again.

Here is an example from [this guide](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/adding-features.html#cooldowns):

```js
const cooldowns = new Discord.Collection();

if (!cooldowns.has(command.name)) {
    cooldowns.set(command.name, new Discord.Collection());
}

const now = Date.now();
const timestamps = cooldowns.get(command.name);
const cooldownAmount = (command.cooldown || 3) * 1000;

if (timestamps.has(message.author.id)) {
    // ...
}
```

```js
if (timestamps.has(message.author.id)) {
    const expirationTime = timestamps.get(message.author.id) + cooldownAmount;

    if (now < expirationTime) {
        const timeLeft = (expirationTime - now) / 1000;
        return message.reply(`please wait ${timeLeft.toFixed(1)} more second(s) before reusing the \`${command.name}\` command.`);
    }
}
```